# Retrieve data from MongoDB collection into Swing JTable

Tags: java, swing, mongodb, jtable, mongodb-java

I am a newbie in database projects. 
I don't know how to display a collection in mongodb inside a swing window (EDIT: JTable) after connecting it to the database server....plz help me out in this...
I have tried doing this in sql but am not able to do using mongodb

```
JButton btnDisplay = new JButton("display");
    btnDisplay.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                // To connect to mongodb server
                MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
                // Now connect to your databases
                DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "test" );
                System.out.println("Connect to database successfully");

                DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("cars");
                DBCursor cursor = coll.find();
            }

            catch (Exception a) {
                a.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DBCursor](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.0/com/mongodb/DBCursor.html) is meant to be iterated through. You can use the [`DBCursor#hasNext()`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.0/com/mongodb/DBCursor.html#hasNext%28%29) like you would a normal `Iterator`, and the [`DBCursor#next()`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.0/com/mongodb/DBCursor.html#next%28%29) to get the next [`DBObject`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.0/com/mongodb/DBObject.html). The `DBObject` allows you to [`get`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.0/org/bson/BSONObject.html#get%28java.lang.String%29) values like you would a `Map`, by passing in the key

So let's say we have a collection `table` in the `swingtest` database, with the following documents

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5450700691a43786388fcc8f"), "first" : "Stack", "last" : "Overflow" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5450704d91a43786388fcc90"), "first" : "Pee", "last" : "Skillet" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5450705a91a43786388fcc91"), "first" : "Hello", "last" : "World" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("545070b091a43786388fcc92"), "first" : "Mongo", "last" : "DB" }
```

You haven't actually specified what you want to do with the collection, so let's say you want to add the data to a `JTable`, you could do something like

```
MongoClient mongoClient = null;
DBCursor cursor = null;
try {
    mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
    DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "swingtest" );
    DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("table");
    cursor = coll.find();

    String[] columnNames = {"id", "First", "Last"};
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);

    while(cursor.hasNext()) {
        DBObject obj = cursor.next();
        String first = (String)obj.get("first");
        String last = (String)obj.get("last");
        ObjectId id = (ObjectId)obj.get("_id");
        model.addRow(new Object[] { id, first, last });
    }
    table.setModel(model);

    cursor.close(); 
    mongoClient.close();
}
```

where for each iteration (document), we get the `_id`, `first` and `last` values, then create a row in which we add the `DefaultTableModel`. At the end of the iterating, we set the model for the `JTable`.

Here's the full example

[image]

```
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;

public class MongoStackoverflow {
    private static JTable table;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                table = new JTable(){
                    @Override
                    public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
                        return new Dimension(300, 150);
                    }
                };
                JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                JButton button = new JButton("Show Data");
                button.addActionListener(listener);
                panel.add(new JScrollPane(table));
                panel.add(button, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(runnable);
    }

    static ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            MongoClient mongoClient = null;
            DBCursor cursor = null;
            try {
                mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
                DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "swingtest" );
                DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("table");
                cursor = coll.find();

                String[] columnNames = {"id", "First", "Last"};
                DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);

                while(cursor.hasNext()) {
                    DBObject obj = cursor.next();
                    String first = (String)obj.get("first");
                    String last = (String)obj.get("last");
                    ObjectId id = (ObjectId)obj.get("_id");
                    model.addRow(new Object[] { id, first, last });
                }
                table.setModel(model);

                cursor.close(); 
                mongoClient.close();
            } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MongoStackoverflow.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } finally {
                if (cursor!= null) {
                    cursor.close();
                }
                if (mongoClient != null) {
                     mongoClient.close();
                }   
            }
        }
    }; 
}
```

---

**Resource**

- [MongoDB Java API Getting Started Guide](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-java-driver/#getting-started-with-java-driver)
- [MongoDB Java API Documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/index.html?_ga=1.137129717.41019472.1414551523)
- [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Comment: sir thanks a lot for devoting your valuable time to answer my query...actually u have answered correctly what i needed though i dint mention it properley... thanks once again...

Comment: sir i have an another problem regarding the same project....i have posted a question on this too...plzzz help me out on this...